# Função jQuery para formatar data por .class

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando fazer um script que recebe a class .data do input e converta a data para pt-br, mas não consigo fazer, gostaria de uma ajuda.

```
$.fn.converteData = function(){
    var data  = ($(this).val()).split("-");     
    var dataf = data[2]+data[1]+data[0];    
    $(this).val(dataf); 
    $(this).mask("99/99/9999"); //estou usando o plugin maskedinput
}

$(".data").converteData();


<form>
<label for="dt_nasc">Data de nascimento</label>
<input class="data" name="dt_nasc" type="text" value="1966-11-27">
</form>
```

Queria que ela já fosse chamada automaticamente para todos inputs html com a classe .data
Eu recebo ela em 1966-11-27 esse script seria pra converter 27/11/1966.

Comment: Pode colocar o HTML que tem? qual é o formato em que essas datas estão e qual é o formato final que quer? (dê exemplos)

Comment: Aqui está funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Sergio, complementei na pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Se compreendo a sua pergunta isto serve para mudar a formatação da data:

```js
$('input.data').each(function () {
    var data = new Date(this.value);
    this.value = [data.getDate(), data.getMonth() + 1, data.getFullYear()].join('/');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label for="dt_nasc">Data de nascimento</label>
    <input class="data" name="dt_nasc" type="text" value="1966-11-27" />
</form>
```

No código converto primeiro a data num objeto data e depois dou o formato final usando métodos nativos para ir buscar o dia, ano e mês.

#### Outra solução, sem fazer parse da data:

```js
$('input.data').each(function () {
    this.value = this.value.split('-').reverse().join('/');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label for="dt_nasc">Data de nascimento</label>
    <input class="data" name="dt_nasc" type="text" value="1966-11-27" />
    <label for="dt_emissao">Data de emissão</label>
    <input class="data" name="dt_nasc" type="text" value="2005-08-25" />
</form>
```

Comment: Rodei o código enviado, deu certo, mas quando tenho mais de uma data no form, a segunda fica errada. 

<form>
    <label for="dt_nasc">Data de nascimento</label>
    <input class="data" name="dt_nasc" type="text" value="1966-11-27" />
    
    <label for="dt_emissao">Data de emissão</label>
    <input class="data" name="dt_nasc" type="text" value="2005-08-25" />
</form>

a segunda data sai 24/8/2005

Comment: @JrJs exato. Não éra isso que queria? Data formatada `dd/mm/aaaa`? Como aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/7e3trkgn/

Comment: @JrJs ah, ok já percebi, problema de fuso horário talvez. Vou juntar outra solução sem fazer parse da data...

Comment: @JrJs juntei outra versão na resposta. Asssim: http://jsfiddle.net/7e3trkgn/1/

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente essa ultima, obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @JrJs ótimo. Se quiser pode marcar a resposta como aceite.